# Failed to run jetifier React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried to run react-native run-android and I got this error.

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable 
    it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
    error Failed to run jetifier. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
    Error: spawnSync C:\Users\JayK\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\jetifier\bin\jetify ENOENT
    at Object.spawnSync (internal/child_process.js:1002:20)
    at spawnSync (child_process.js:614:24)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:642:13)
    at Object.runAndroid [as func] (C:\Users\JayK\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:101:41)
    at Command.handleAction (C:\Users\JayK\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:21)
    at Command.listener (C:\Users\JayK\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\JayK\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (C:\Users\JayK\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\commander\index.js:474:21)
    at setupAndRun (C:\Users\JayK\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:210:24)
```

Comment: Are you wanting to include Android X? If so, you'll need to run jetifier. Could you comment on whether you want to Android X-ify your project and I'll provide the answer.

Comment: Please check your gradlew batch file. It should have executible flag on if you are using Mac or Linux Ubantu. It was the only thing that prevented me and gave the error above, all the time. When you sync, the property seldom resets.

Comment: make sure you are not in android subfolder I had jetifier error when accidentally running from there

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use this :

step 1:  add these two lines in gradlew.properties  [Visit for complete guideline](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

> android.useAndroidX=true 
>     android.enableJetifier=true

step 2: use these commands

First of all remove node_modules folder and reinstall it using

```sh
npm install
```

or

```sh
yarn
```

and then

```sh
npm install --save-dev jetifier 
npx jetify  
npx react-native run-android
```

Call

```sh
npx jetify
```

every time when (your dependencies update or every time you install node_modules you have to jetify again)

Comment: Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

Answer (score 42):

When I was getting this error I noticed that I'm not in the main project folder I was inside the `cd android` folder. So I just `cd ..` it and it worked.

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked for me!

Comment: This is the solution

Comment: I didn't notice that until read your answer. Thanks a log

Answer (score 16):

If you run `npx react-native run-android` in android folder. That error will happen.  You need to run-android in the root directory.

Comment: dude you are life saver i am about to follow the most voted answer

Answer (score 12):

Use this:

`react-native run-android --no-jetifier`

Comment: What do you suggest if jetifier needed ? Stack trace already say that 

_You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag._

Comment: This issue discussing on [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25667)

Comment: I dont want to use --no-jetifier ie. I want the jetifier

Answer (score 5):

I'm using yarn so I had to use

`yarn react-native run-android --variant=release`

(Not `npx`)

Also to run in the simulator (not on a device) I had to install some extra stuff in Android Studio, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64942777/3469524

Answer (score 3):

react-native run-android --no-jetifier

and again start server

react-native start

Answer (score 2):

Mostly it happened by cache, metro server closed or already generated package in android folder. check jetifier is enabled in `gradle.proporties`

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = true
```

1. First close your `metro server` terminal window and run `$ yarn android` // this is almost solve your issue otherwise follow the below steps
2. Then run

   `$ cd android && ./gradlew clean`
3. Clean the cache and build folders - generated & intermediates

   `$ ./gradlew cleanBuildCache`
4. Create the debug apk

   `$ ./gradlew AssembleDebug` //output: Build successful

   then check your apk output folder.
5. Run the react native package

   `$ yarn android || npx react-native run-android`

Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in React Native CLI v2.6.1

Use Below steps to resolve the issue:

- If you use lock files (yarn.lock or package-lock.json) - find the @react-native-community/cli entry, remove it, run yarn install / npm install once again.
- If you don't use lock files – remove node_modules and run yarn install / npm install again.
- Run yarn list @react-native-community/cli or npm list @react-native-community/cli and verify you're on the latest version (v2.6.2).
- Run react-native run-android

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following command in the project's directory:

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier
```

Answer (score 1):

Check current directory set to project root and then run `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

One reason will be you are not in the main project folder. assured that  you are not at **cd android folder**.

Another solution: **make sure**
just set env variable if you are in windows like shown below:::

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change from "C" directory to any other directory and then install/run starting from here 
"npm install -g react-native-cli"  .
Then create new project "react-native init AwesomeProject "
use Yarn to install dependencies fast.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use this `react-native run-android --no-jetifier` worked me