# Stuck when run react-native application

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I run react-native application in emulator but when I run `npx react-native run-android --no-jetifier`, run stuck and do nothing:

[image]

My emulator:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 0):

It won't work if there is a lib that requires jetifier eg. react-native-gesture-handler.
If there is no lib as such then delete the node_modules and npm install and try again.

Comment: it started project when I run `react-native init AppName`, if I not use `jetifier`, run still stuck and I get this message ```info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 863 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...```

Comment: Follow this accepted answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048978/failed-to-run-jetifier-react-native