# React Native, react-native run-android close automatically after build successfully

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to run my react native app in my physical device by starting server first with `react-native start` and then run in my device with `react-native run-android` however when it build successfully it's closing automatically.
That happen when I run `react-native run-android`

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1752 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :react-native-firebase
react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from C:\Users\DAWOR\Go-polo-master\node_modules\react-native\android

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\DAWOR\Go-polo-master\android\app\google-services.json

> Task :app:installDebug
07:10:22 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
07:10:22 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on '4200336f97fc7483' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:10:22 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'SM-G615F - 8.1.0' for app:debug
07:10:22 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device '4200336f97fc7483'
07:10:22 D/Device: Uploading file onto device '4200336f97fc7483'
07:10:22 D/ddms: Reading file permision of C:\Users\DAWOR\Go-polo-master\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
07:10:24 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:10:48 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '4200336f97fc7483' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:10:48 V/ddms: execute: returning
07:10:48 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:10:48 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '4200336f97fc7483' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:10:48 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 42s
318 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 315 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "4200336f97fc7483"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.gopro/.MainActivity }
PS C:\Users\DAWOR\Go-polo-master>
```

I tried to clean cache but it's throw error when I run `npm cache clean` and when I use `npm cache clean --force` it show `npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.`
Anyone can tell me whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Step # 1 ( Add these 2 lines in gradlew.properties )

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Step # 2

```
npm install
npm install --save-dev jetifier 
npx jetify  
npx react-native run-android
```

Step # 3 (Call)

```
npx jetify
```

More detail found here [failed-to-run-jetifier-react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048978/failed-to-run-jetifier-react-native)

Comment: step 1 already defined in gradlew.properties, step 2 npm install throws an error

Comment: Try "yarn" command then "npx jetify" and npx react-native run-android

Comment: yarn always throws that error  `error Can't add "react-native-parsed-text": invalid package version undefined.`

Comment: and there is not react-native-parsed-text in package.json