# Unable to strip library *.so due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is

Tags: qt, android-ndk

Today I noticed that I get warnings while building a QT app for Android:

```
Unable to strip library *.so due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
```

What tool is missing? Does it try to strip debug info or something else?

I have [NDK (Side by side)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58823679/2394762) installed:

[image]

the app is built with NDK 22.1.7171670.

I also have command line tools and CMake installed:

[image]

**EDIT1**

With ARM builds I got the same warnings, also I noticed that there are warnings like

```
> Task :extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables
Unable to extract native debug metadata from E:\repos\examples\src\MyApp\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib\x86_64\libc++_shared.so
because unable to locate the objcopy executable for the x86_64 ABI.
```

so I have an impression that Gradle cannot locate `strip.exe` and `objcopy.exe` tools for some reason.

Another question is does Google app store strip debug information automatically?

Comment: i want to colaborate with you to build an app with qt please

Comment: @rn3w hi! what kind of collaboration are you interested in?

Comment: programing with c++ qt building an android app

Comment: @rn3w how can I help? Leave me message via my website https://developernote.com/contact/

Comment: X86_64 definitely cannot refer to ARM processor which most of Androids are using. Only Intel Atom based Android could probably relate to X86_64. But that one is quite rare.

Comment: @AlexanderV it is for testing on the emulator

Comment: @Dmitriano is emulator running ARM-based Android or Intel-based?

Comment: @AlexanderV I am not sure what do you mean by '-based`, could you clarify please?

Comment: @Dmitriano that emulator is to emulate other processor code to run on your computer CPU. You need to know what other processor code supposed to run in Android emulator. Most frequently it is ARM processor code and all that runs in emulator as Linux, Android OS, apps and their libraries supposed to be for ARM. What X86_64 stands for is about Intel/AMD architecture. That binary library cannot be accepted on the wrong emulator which is intended for ARM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a wrong Gradle configuration. I updated Android Temple with QT Creator and `stripReleaseDebugSymbols` started to work.